# Can I not hate homosexuals?

Tags: homosexuality

I'm a young girl, turning twelve in June 8th, with a personality that I think is a sin, which is: accepting people no matter what.

I have always known that being homosexual is a sin, but never really cared about it. Like, if an idol of mine came out as gay/lesbian, I would never see them differently. I would think: they are still human and breath, have a heart and feelings, but they are committing a sin that is probably worse than murder, but they are still human in my eyes.  It is the future and there are thousands and thousands of homosexual and we should never care about it, only if they pressured you into becoming one.

Can I not hate homosexuals?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with tolerating others beliefs, as long as it does not affect you "make you become one", after all we can't make everyone have the same beliefs

Comment: The act of homosexuality is definitely not equal in evil to murder. Perhaps it is equal with adultery though. And being homosexual is not a sin at all provided you don't act on it.

Answer (score 4):

Imho, Islam bans and shows hate to actions(sins) not to people. So even somebody could be full of sins but Islam still consider them as people and speaks to them. If we cant talk to sinners or non believers, how we can explain and tell beauty of Islam to them? Islam always suggest to people ask forgiveness for sins. So people are not object of hatred.

You can read more from: [Abu Amina Elias- Love the sinner, hate the sin in Islam](http://abuaminaelias.com/love-the-sinner-hate-the-sin-in-islam/)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let me conduct a thought experiment: Let us take a random brother in Islam called **A**. Don't you love Abu Bakr (RA) more than you love **A**? I definitely do. Why? Because of Abu Bakr (RA)'s actions. Now let us take a random non-Muslim brother in humanity called **B**. Don't you love **B** more than you love Abu Jahl? Of course. Because of Abu Jahl's actions.

So, you see, actions that are chosen willingly with the proper knowledge are very much the fault of that person themselves and it is valid to dislike such a person. Do you treat a murderer equal to a non-murderer because you only dislike the murder not the person himself? It simply doesn't make sense.

But, the distinction that is done is that no living person should become hated beyond redemption. This is because the fact that Allah has kept them alive tells us that Allah thinks they have a chance at redemption. This concept is explained in the following hadith:

> "Love your beloved moderately, perhaps he becomes hated to you someday. And hate whom you hate moderately, perhaps he becomes your beloved someday." ([Jami` at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/103))

(Notice also how the Prophet (SAW) doesn't admonish people from hating. Just hating excessively.)

So, what needs to be taken away is that there are layers of love. The base level is you love a person for them being your brother in humanity and having a chance at goodness. So you must work with that person to bring them towards goodness and pray for their guidance. Then either that love deteriorates because of their sins or increases because of their goodness. But there must always be a small amount of love as long as they are alive.

Thus, you should definitely not love a person equally once you find out he is committing a sin. If you do, you need to look into yourself and recheck your priorities. Why do you love this person so much that them being sinful doesn't take away from that love at all? Be careful of idolatry. You don't need a literal idol in front of you to commit it. A Muslim must love only for the sake of Allah.

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: If anyone loves for Allah's sake, hates for Allah's sake, gives for Allah's sake and withholds for Allah's sake, he will have perfect faith. ([Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/42/86))

***Note: Only the act of homosexuality is considered a sin.***

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah hir rahman nir raheem
As sallamu alaykum wa rahmatullah wa baraktuhu.
I ask allah the most generous to befriend you in this world and the next and make your path towards him easy.
Today the muslims are being tested in regards to their belief meaning they are being influenced to not leave islam but leave the islam which the prophet Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم was upon his companions and the prophets before him.
The belief accepting people no matter what , depends on what you mean.
In regards to homosexuals allah has said its harram and those who engage in it are sinful regardless wether it is a celebrity you like because you should love allah and his messenger more than anyone else and love what they love and hate what they hate.
Non muslims and sinful people will always try to make islam  compatible with their choices like when  Allah revealed surah kafiroon and told the prophet Muhammad when the mushrikeen said to him we will worship for a few days allah and you worship our idols a few days Allah revealed"say o disbelievers i  do not worship what you worship neither will you worship what i worship ......for you is your religion and to yours is mine".

But we have to live amongst all types of people from non muslims to homosexuals etc so we dont persecute them but we advise them and tell them what their upon is false and we dont sit with them except when helping or advising them because a person is upon the religion of his friend.
Hence ibraheem alayhi salam the messenger said in surah 60vs4 on first page Allah said he said to his people "theres a good example in ibraheem and his people when they said to their people we are free from you and what you worship besides allah" point here is we are free from you and your actions.

Know with the rebellious will always try to show them love and some will be guided and come to islam but understand the rebellious will never love or be pleased with you back until you follow their religion meaning you make halal what they make halal or you accept it and don't show your disapproval 
Allah says in surah 2 vs 120 And never will the Jews or the Christians approve of you until you follow their religion. Say, "Indeed, the guidance of Allah is the  guidance." If you were to follow their desires after what has come to you of knowledge, you would have against Allah no protector or helper.
Conclusion it is upon you to learn the correct belief system from those who understand the religion and cling to it with your molar teeth.
And to allah is the return.
Allah knows best

Answer (score -1):

I personally wouldnt consider it as a sin.

Anyone has the chance to repent and be forgiven, so we shouldnt judge anyone (only Allah SWT has the authority for that).

"The Penalty on the Day of Judgment will be doubled to him (disbeliever), and he will dwell therein in ignominy,- unless he repents, believes, and works righteous deeds, for Allah will change the evil of such persons into good, and Allah is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful. And whoever repents and does good has truly turned to Allah with an (acceptable) conversion."
— Quran, Sura 25 (Al-Furqan), ayah 69-71, Translation Yousaf Ali